# How to keep the 1st record of duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I know there are many questions over this and many solutions, most of them specific to each individual's case. However, in my case I cannot seem to get just the sets of records that are to be deleted, to leave only the 1st ID or the lowest-value ID.

This is a sample of my table:

[image]

```
ID          COL_A                               COL_B   what I need to do
24556552    KD PT PERSONAL TRAINING, AND 58 MOU 5691212 
24556924    KD PT PERSONAL TRAINING, AND 58 MOU 5691212 <-- remove
24556869    KHETSHI DHARAMSHI & CO LTD,         5690443 
24556951    KHETSHI DHARAMSHI & CO LTD,         5690443 <-- remove
24528435    KINNY TINT LDA                      5689791 
24528436    KINNY TINT LDA                      5689791 <-- remove
24528437    KINNY TINT LDA                      5689791 <-- remove
24528438    KINNY TINT LDA                      5689791 <-- remove
24528439    KINNY TINT LDA                      5689791 <-- remove
```

Is there a way to link this table back to itself, so I can only get the first occurrence of it, keep it and delete the rest? I am not familiar with PARTITION OVER etc.

Thanks

Comment: Since you have seen the many similar questions, and tries yourself, please show us and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: "I am not familiar with PARTITION OVER " - the documentation is very clear and helpful.

Comment: @DaleK Ok with images in my OP, but they are accepted in SO, and don't assume what is "clear and helpful"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to *view* your data sans the duplicates, use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL_A, COL_B ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, COL_A, COL_B
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you really need to *delete* the duplicate records, then use exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.COL_A = t1.COL_A AND
          t2.COL_B = t1.COL_B AND
          t2.ID < t1.ID
);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, unlike some up there #eyeroll

Comment: @Fandango68 I wouldn't have marked your question duplicate.

Comment: @DaleK Are you joking?  First, when I answered it was not marked duplicate, and second, I don't agree that it is an _exact_ duplicate.